# IIS: published asp.net app replace ip with domain name

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, ip

I have already rent an online server.
I'm installing IIS on it, hosting a website on it.
to access the site from internet, I must type: {ipaddress}/siteAppName
My question is how to use a name instead of ip address? should I buy and register a new domain name? if that the case how could I configure this ip with a new domain name?

**More Details:**
I am renting a dedicated server... so I have full access to the server as I'm hosting my website on it. but I don't have a domain name. either from local machine or remotely I can successfully access the hosted website using the ip address of my server/webAppName.. but the problem is that I'm trying to get ssl certificate, but the generated CSR is rejected from all SSL suppliers because the url is not accepted, and I think that it's not accepted because of using IP instead of a domain name. I mentioned many self-conclusions here, but I'm not sure about any of them... That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your hoster but most allow you to use a registered domain name.  They should have instructions on how to set this up.

Comment: I am renting a dedicated server... so I have full access to the server as I'm hosting my website on it. but I don't have a domain name.

Comment: Does the company you are renting the server from have instructions on how to set this up?

Comment: I'm Not sure.. The company is godaddy, I'll check it's website for any possible instruction.